# how to compare 2 list of files with same filesnames except extension a remove only matches shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script

for each file `.ext1` i generate a second file `.ext2` with same filename except for extension, and then i remove all `.ext1` files. The process can sometimes fail, so i would like no know how to remove only `.ext1` files that have their `.ext2` counterpart. I want something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ext1s=$(ls -l *.ext1 2>/dev/null | wc -l)
if [ $ext1s -ge 0 ]; then
  generates .ext2 files
  ext2s=$(ls -l *.ext2 2>/dev/null | wc -l)
  if [ $ext1s -eq $ext2s ]; then
    rm *.ext1
  else
    what i need
  fi
else
  echo no .ext1 files
  exit
fi
```

Comment: For a start `$ext1` is not defined. Run your script through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate the `*.ext2` files and delete the matching `.ext1` file if it exists.

```
for f in *.ext2;do rm -f "$(basename "$f" .ext2).ext1";done
```

`basename` not only extracts the file name from a full path, it will also remove the extension if provided with a 2nd argument, so `"$(basename "$f" .ext2).ext1"` removes the `.ext2` extension and replaces it with `.ext1`.

`-f` on `rm` keeps is silent if the `.ext1` file doesn't exist.

A basename-less version of the same is:

```
for f in *.ext2;do rm -f "${f%.ext2}.ext1";done
```

Comment: nice solution, it is more efficient than mine... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution, if there is a better way to do it, please share.

```
#!/bin/bash

ext1s=$(ls -l *.ext1 2>/dev/null | wc -l)
if [ $ext1s -ge 0 ]; then
  generates .ext2 files
  ext2s=$(ls -l *.ext2 2>/dev/null | wc -l)
  if [ $ext1s -eq $ext2s ]; then
    rm *.ext1
  else
    list=$(comm -12 <(find *.ext1 -type f -exec bash -c 'basename "${0%.*}"' {} \; | sort) <(find *.ext2 -type f -exec bash -c 'basename "${0%.*}"' {} \; | sort))
    for file in $list ; do
      rm $file.ext1
    done
  fi
else
  echo no .ext1 files
  exit
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I dislike the use of unnecessary external programs and the consequent overhead: the questioner's solution schedules `ls` (twice), `wc` (twice), `find` (twice), `comm`, `bash` (twice), `basename` (twice) and `sort` (twice).

None of these is required: they can all be handled by `bash` internals:-

```
for f in *.ext1
do   if [ "$f" == "*.ext1" ]
     then echo no files
     elif [ -e "${f%.ext1}.ext2" ]
     then rm "$f"
     else
          # Insert here the code to create the .ext2 file from "$f"
     fi
done
```

If no files match `*.ext1` then `f` will be set to this single value; otherwise, the loop will be traversed for each matching file. (Note: if you are mad enough to create a file with the literal name `*.ext1`, then the "no files" check will fail.)

For each `.ext1` file, the existence of a corresponding `.ext2` file is checked: if it exists, the `.ext1` is deleted; otherwise, the code is invoked to create the `.ext2` file (optionally, if this is successful, the original `.ext1` file can be removed, avoiding future superfluous `.ext1` files).

Comment: it's a good answer, but it has the same flaw as mine, it loops on .ext1 files...

Comment: @LuisGómezGuzmán - I understood that you want to convert any unprocessed `.ext1` or delete any processed ones, so the script loops through all the `.ext1` files it finds. Where's the flaw?

Comment: Hi, I didn't express myself very well. It's not a flaw. Deletion is done after generating `.ext2` files. Therefore, looping on `.ext1` files and check if `.ext2` file exists then delete it's least optimal than loop on `.ext2` files and delete the `.ext1` file (no checking so no if condition).

Comment: @LuisGómezGuzmán - Your original script contains the line `generates .ext2 files`, which I took as pseudo-code to indicate that you want to convert `.ext1` files within the script, which you can't do if you scan only the `.ext2` files. If you want only to delete converted `.ext1` files, then of course it is more efficient to scan only the `.ext2` files, but this isn't how I read your requirements.

Comment: I see. Anyway, I have other uses in mind for your response. Thanks.